# How to prevent printing space in the last loop of a for loop

Tags: c

a simple question for you guys:

I wrote this loop that prints some values of an array.
i want space between every value but i would not like to have a space after the last value that the code prints.

any idea how do i do this without complicating too much?

```
for (i_talltrees=1; i_talltrees<=numtrees; i_talltrees++) {
    pre=i_talltrees-1;
    post=i_talltrees+1;
    if (talltrees[pre]<talltrees[i_talltrees]&&talltrees[i_talltrees]>talltrees[post]) {
        printf("%d ", talltrees[i_talltrees]);
    }

    }
```

Comment: put another if statement in?

Comment: As an aside, are you sure this is right? `i_talltrees<=numtrees`.  Looks like you have an off by one. And yeah, use an `if` to check if you are on the last item.

Comment: if you don't have problem in having an extra space at the beginning, change `"%d "` to `" %d"`.

Comment: @EdS. No. The starting value of the `i_talltrees` variable is 1, not 0. (assuming that there are enough elements in the array, this should be fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 int flag = 0; 
 if (talltrees[pre]<talltrees[i_talltrees]&&talltrees[i_talltrees]>talltrees[post]) 
 {   
    if(flag)
    { 
        printf(" ");
        flag = 0;
    }
    printf("%d", talltrees[i_talltrees]); 
    flag = 1; 
 }
```

Comment: I think part of the problem is that it may or may not print at any given value of `i_talltrees`. A simple `if` like yours would work great if the value at `numtrees` did enter the `if`, but it doesn't fix the problem if it doesn't.

Comment: @Macattack; See the condition in the `for` loop: `i_talltrees<=numtrees`. It will enter for `numtrees`.

Comment: The issue isn't whether or not it will enter, i.e. out of bounds, the problem is, will it pass the conditional: `talltrees[pre]<talltrees[i_talltrees]&&talltrees[i_talltrees]>talltrees[post]`. If `[numtrees-1]` succeeds, a `" "` will be appended, but if `[numtrees]` fails then there will be a trailing space.

Comment: @Macattack Huh...? What? How is "a `" "` will be appended" different from "there will be a trailing space"? You are confused...

Comment: @H2CO3 Unclear maybe, confused, no. The code only prints if the conditional is passed. Agreed? If the last value, at `talltrees[numtrees]`, fails the conditional, then there will have been a `" "` printed with no numbers following it. Is there anything unclear about that?

Comment: @haccks Because your answer is broken for the case where the last value in the array doesn't pass the conditional and so doesn't print.

Comment: @Macattack; I think you are confused. `if(i_talltrees != numtrees)` is inside the previous `if` (nested `if`s).

Comment: @haccks I've created a simple example which represents the problem case I'm talking about [here](http://codepad.org/9Mz1INw4).

Comment: @Macattack; OK. Got your point. I agreed. I [fixed it](http://codepad.org/JM39V9nm). :). Notice `for (i = 1; i < len-1; i++)`, I did this as per the OP's condition.

Comment: @haccks It suffers the same problem, if you change the [conditional to < 3](http://codepad.org/Ae03m9ZO), you'll get a trailing space. You can't print a space until you know you'll be printing a number to follow it.

Comment: @haccks Now you've got it. You just need to initialize `flag` to `0` and I'll up vote this.

Comment: @Macattack; That was typo.

Answer (score 1):

This should prevent leading or trailing spaces:

```
int have_printed = 0;

for (i_talltrees=1; i_talltrees<=numtrees; i_talltrees++) {
    pre=i_talltrees-1;
    post=i_talltrees+1;
    if (talltrees[pre]<talltrees[i_talltrees]&&talltrees[i_talltrees]>talltrees[post]) {
        if (have_printed) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else {
            have_printed = 1; 
        }
        printf("%d", talltrees[i_talltrees]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vary the format

```
const char *format = "%d";
for (i_talltrees=1; i_talltrees<=numtrees; i_talltrees++) {
  pre=i_talltrees-1;
  post=i_talltrees+1;
  if (talltrees[pre]<talltrees[i_talltrees]&&talltrees[i_talltrees]>talltrees[post]) {
    printf(format, talltrees[i_talltrees]);
    format = " %d";   // next, if any, begin with a space.
  }
}
```