# How do I print out something different at the last item of a loop, C programming

Tags: c

```
Please enter an integer: 1234
Digit: 4
Digit: 3
Digit: 2
Digit: 1
```

I have a program right now that prints out an integer's digits in reverse. Instead of the output above, I'd like to have:

```
Please enter an integer: 1234
Digit: 4
Digit: 3
Digit: 2
Last Digit: 1
```

How do i make that happen? 
Here's my code by the way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int input;
    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
int num = input;
int i = 0;
while(num > 0)
{
    int remainder = num % 10;
    num = num /10;
    i++;
    printf("Digit: %d\n", remainder );
}
return 0;
}
```

How do I print something else at the last item of the loop?

Comment: Note that if the user is careless and enters `0`, they will see no output at all.  Ditto for negative numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667080/how-to-prevent-printing-space-in-the-last-loop-of-a-for-loop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589821/how-to-pretty-print-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing to see if the while condition will fail is one way.

```
 while (num > 0) {
    int remainder = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    i++;
    if (num > 0) {
        printf("Digit: %d\n", remainder);
    } else {
        printf("Last Digit: %d\n", remainder);
    }
 }
```

Or change the while condition...

```
 while (num > 9) {
    int remainder = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    i++;
    printf("Digit: %d\n", remainder);   
 }
 printf("Last Digit: %d\n", num);
```

Comment: The second option is good because it prints `Last Digit: 0` for zero.  It also prints a negative digit for negative inputs, which should probably be handled separately. The `%` is not really necessary for non-negative inputs (in the last print statement).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if (num > 0) //Indicates that there are more digits to come
{
    printf("Digit: %d\n", remainder );
} 
else // Otherwise, it is the last digit
{
    printf("Last Digit: %d\n", remainder);
}
```

Instead of just

```
printf("Last Digit: %d\n", remainder);
```